# elasticsearch query also matches terms that have dashes in it

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a query similar to the one below

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "category": "men_fashion"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "category": "western_clothing"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "category": "shirts"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that it also fetches products that are in the category 
"t-shirts". How can i restrict this it to only find exact matches?

UPDATES: Here is the code i am using for mapping

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "products": {
            "properties": {
                "variations": {
                    "type": "nested"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is an actual sample product**

```
{
    "title": "100% Cotton Unstitched Suit For Men",
    "slug": "100-cotton-unstitched-suit-for-men",
    "price": 200,
    "sale_price": 0,
    "vendor_id": 32,
    "featured": 0,
    "viewed": 20,
    "stock": 4,
    "sku": "XXX-B",
    "rating": 0,
    "active": 1,
    "vendor_name": "vendor_name",
    "category": [
        "men_fashion",
        "traditional_clothing",
        "unstitched_fabric"
    ],
    "image": "imagename.jpg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "variation_id": "34",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-C",
            "size": "m",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "35",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-D",
            "size": "l",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In most cases this is a mapping issue. Could you please extend your question with some sample documents? If the category is an array field you could probably solve it by just using keyword mapping as these values look like fixed strings that don't require analyzing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide any information about your mapping so I assume you have a  standard analyzer applied to the `category` field. Looking at your query (filter syntax) I also assume that you work with ES version lower than 5.0.

With standard analyzer, following terms for `category` field are created when indexing `t-shirt` documents:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=t-shirt
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "t",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 1,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "shirt",
            "start_offset": 2,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

So now when you search for `shirts`, you also get `t-shirts` documents.

If the `category` field in your use case could not be analyzed (you do not need full text search), then just mark the `category` field as `not_analyzed`.

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "index":    "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to keep the capability to anaylze the `category` content, then you could use [Whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) (dash will not be treated as a word delimiter):

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use [Keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) but it would be similar to `not_analyzed` option.

It all depends on your needs, but all solutions require to change the mapping of your index. You can check the behaviour of analyzer with:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_analyze?analyzer=whitespace&text=t-shirt
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_analyze?analyzer=keyword&text=t-shirt
http://127.0.0.1:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=t-shirt
```

#### Additional info

Basically you are searching on `category` field, so the fact that `variations` is nested isn't importatnt here. `category` field with type `string` can hold an array of values, it's also not a problem here.

With this mapping (note `"analyzer": "whitespace"`):

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/test
{
    "mappings": {
        "products": {
            "properties": {
                "variations": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "size":    { "type": "string" },
                        "color":   { "type": "string" },
                        ... // other nested fields
                    }
                },
                "category":    { 
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "whitespace"
                },
                ... // other fields
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I indexed two documents

**Document 1**:

```
{
    "category": [
        "men_fashion",
        "traditional_clothing",
        "unstitched_fabric",
        "shirts"
    ],
    "image": "imagename.jpg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "variation_id": "34",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-C",
            "size": "m",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Document 2**:

```
{
    "category": [
        "men_fashion",
        "traditional_clothing",
        "unstitched_fabric",
        "t-shirts"
    ],
    "image": "imagename.jpg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "variation_id": "34",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-C",
            "size": "m",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "35",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-D",
            "size": "l",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when I search with:

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "category": "men_fashion"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "category": "shirts"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get only Document 1.

You can add `"analyzer": "whitespace"` also to nested `variations.color` etc. field in a similiar way if you need (but search query would also have to be changed to search over nested docs).

Comment: Thanks joanna, my mapping is a bit different than yours. I have updated my answer with the code i am using for mapping. Please have a look

Comment: Is `category` field inside `variations`, so that you have a document like `{ "variations": { "category" : "t-shirts", "otherField": "..." } }`? I'm asking because I don't see any "nested" syntax in your query. If not, please post a simplified version of your document and version of Elasticsearch you're working with. I'll try to check it.